# Reverting changes to an EntitySet<T> in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext, entityset

I have a Linq-to-SQL context with changes in an EntitySet. I want to get rid of all the changes I made to it since I last called `SubmitChanges()`. I use the following method to revert the state of the context:

```
public static void RevertChanges(this DataContext context)
{
    var changeSet = context.GetChangeSet();
    var inserts = changeSet.Inserts.ToList();
    var deleteAndUpdate = changeSet.Deletes.Concat(changeSet.Updates).ToList();

    foreach (var inserted in inserts)
    {
        var table = context.GetTable(inserted.GetType());   
        table.DeleteOnSubmit(inserted);
    }

    if (deleteAndUpdate.Count > 0)
    {
        context.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, deleteAndUpdate);
    }
}
```

This works fine, except that an `EntitySet` based on the table doesn't get refreshed, and keeps the changes in it.

What is the best way to reject the modifications in an `EntitySet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way?

```
using (DataContext dc = new DataContext)
{

}
```

It's the only way to be sure.

A second best option would be to new up an EntitySet and assign it to the property - same way is done in the designer.cs file.

Comment: Ugh. This is difficult due to how the DataContext is used. I'm looking for a way to avoid this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the 2nd option - it looks promising. How do I refresh the entities in the EntitySet after I recreate it?

Comment: Ok, I solved it by issuing a requery on the context and filling the EntitySet manually.